# Batch Variable Loop Inquiry

Tags: windows, loops, variables, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch to first off grab all folder names in a directory and output those to a txt file.

```
dir "C:\directory1\directory2\directory1\work" > C:\output.txt /b /o
```

Then, run a program specific backup function that requires a folder name to match the outputs of above.  I can send it through a loop but I need the names to be used as variables.  Example: there's a folder names "Test_Test1" and another named "Test2_Test3" that I backup using the output above. I then need to run a batch command which would look like the statement below if running it against a single line

```
staging-backup Test_Test1 C:\BackupLocation\Test_Test1
```

I want to automate this process by grabbing all folder names, throwing them in to a file(if necessary) and then running the above command on all lines but updating the Test_Test1 in both the name (reference location) and the backup location folder(which will be created).

I got as far as using DelayedExpansion to create the variables but hit a head scratcher as I couldnt wrap my brain around how to grab these variables and input them via another loop to run the staging-backup portion of the batch.

For reference, below is my DelayedExpansion setup
    @echo off
    set "file=C:\output.txt"

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
<"!file!" (
  for /f %%i in ('type "!file!" ^| find /c /v ""') do set /a n=%%i && for /l     %%j in (1 1 %%i) do (
    set /p "line_%%j="
  )
)

echo Number of lines: !n! 
echo.
echo !n! > c:\lines.txt
echo Line contents:
for /l %%i in (1 1 !n!) do echo(!line_%%i!
echo.

pause
```

Any ideas on how best to tackle that?  I'm combining these in to 1 batch if possible so I'd need the variables to stick around momentarily while the work is being done. I guess I'm just struggling to figure out how to call these variables in a variable for the staging-backup command that I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea :

```
@Echo off&cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a $count=1
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "C:\directory1\directory2\directory1\work" /b/o') do (
  md "C:\BackupLocation\%%a-!$Count!" 2>nul
  staging-backup "%%a-!$Count!" "C:\BackupLocation\%%a-!$Count!"
  set /a $Count+=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I made soem edits as the -!$Count! was adding -1, -2 etc to the folders which I decided against doing as the folders are unique names anyways.  I also found that I needed to change the formatting a tad and ended with this below:

    md "C:\BackupLocation\
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set /a $count=1
    cd /d C:\staging-backup\location
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "C:\directory1\directory2\directory1\work"     /b/o') do (
    staging-backup "%%a" "C:\BackupLocation\%%a"
    cd /d C:\staging-backup\location
    set /a $Count+=1
    )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info!  I made soem edits as the -!$Count! was adding -1, -2 etc to the folders which I decided against doing as the folders are unique names anyways.  I also found that I needed to change the formatting a tad and ended with this below:

```
md "C:\BackupLocation\
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a $count=1
cd /d C:\staging-backup\location
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "C:\directory1\directory2\directory1\work"     /b/o') do (
staging-backup "%%a" "C:\BackupLocation\%%a"
cd /d C:\staging-backup\location
set /a $Count+=1
)
```

I've got some additional changes to make as I'm going to add in some logging and such but this was my main hurdle.  Thanks for the help!